# Android - There is no android project named

Tags: android, eclipse, export

Dang. I'm sorry for asking so many different questions here. So, I have an android project that I imported into my workspace. Then, after fixing any build path errors and stuff, I went to export it. When I first imported it, it was automatically name "MainActivity". So, I tried to export it but I get the error "There is no android project named MainActivity. I checked and the folder is in my workspace. I searched but couldn't find a working answer. I guess eclipse sees this code as something else. I'm almost positive when I imported it I selected to import exisiting android application project...

Comment: Also, if I try to run it on an emulator I get: "Android Library Projects cannot be launched"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are trying to run your Library Project, if the project is not library
Right Click on the Project >> Properties >> Android >> In the right Panel Scroll down >> Uncheck `isLibrary`

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse probably sees your project as a library instead of an Android project.
Check your project.properties file (you'll find it as the very last file in your project in Package Explorer on the left). If at the bottom you see the line:

```
android.library=true
```

Just get rid of it, or try setting it to `false`. It should normally solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably you had set your project as library.
Try to change the setting at Project > Properties > Android > Library and UNCHECK Is Library