# There is no android project named while exporting

Tags: android

I am able to run my project but when I try to export it says " There is no android project named 'project name'". I have not declared this project as library. I tried to disable lint check, cleaning and building. project.properties also looks fine.

any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15668481/3465623

Comment: I have tried but in my case my project is not declared as library project.

Comment: is your workspace and project directory are different place ?

Comment: It's just a suggestion . Check your project.properties for android.library=true

Comment: no they are in same folder

Comment: i have removed line android.library=false from project.properties file but still problem persist

Comment: Your question says you have  disabled the android Lint check. So try enabling the same and check  the warnings . There may be something which needs attention.

Comment: I tried but unsuccessful...

Answer (score 0):

Guess You are trying to run your Library Project, if the project is not library
Right Click on the Project >> Properties >> Android >> In the right Panel Scroll down >> Uncheck `isLibrary`
Refer similar question here : [Android - There is no android project named](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15668405/3492139)

Comment: You could at least change the text:  stackoverflow.com/a/15668481/3465623

Comment: thanks for fast reply but "isLibarary" is unchecked in properties.

Comment: @Akagami: I posted it before you posted as comments and hence do not downvote!!

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia You are copying the answer of other person without giving credits... So rightful of you.

Comment: @Akagami: Credits given. I posted the answer and saw your comments. It was the same. Hence did not give credits. Now answer edited. Thank you!